# передача данных из представления в контроллер

Tags: javascript, angularjs

В проект подключенно дерево каталогов.
В модуле:

```
import 'angular-tree-control/css/tree-control.css';
```

У меня это дерево используется в темплейте, в компоненте. Все нормально работает. Но, не получается получить данные из selectedNode в своем контроллере CatalogUpdateController который подключен к этому компоненту.

```
const CatalogUpdateComponent:ng.IComponentOptions = {
controller: CatalogUpdateController,
template: `
<div class="container catalog-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <treecontrol class="tree-classic"
                tree-model="$ctrl.dataForTheTree"
                options="$ctrl.treeOptions"
                on-selection="showSelected(node)"
                selected-node="selectedNode">
                назва: {{node.name}} ({{node.id}})
            </treecontrol>
        </div>
<p>Выбранное дерево: <span class="selected-tree-name">{{selectedNode? 
selectedNode.name:"не выбрано"}}</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

Пока что, я их получаю с помощью data-атрибута, но я думаю что это не очень правильно. Вот так :

```
data-sel="{{selectedNode?selectedNode.id:false}}"
```

А в контроллере так :

```
  catalog(){
this.getId = document.querySelector('.selected-tree-name').getAttribute("data-sel")
};
```

Дерево взято отсюда :https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control

Вообщем, как можно получить данные в свой контроллер из selectedNode, и что бы я постоянно видел изменения там, в случае клика по разным заголовкам деревьев (смена id дерева к примеру).
У меня небольшой опыт с angularjs, зашел в тупик. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `$ctrl.selectedNode` в шаблоне, а в контроллере вот так `this.getId = this.selectedNode`.

Comment: Спасибо. 
Рашил проблему по вашему примеру. Только пришлось еще в <treecontrol>  к  `selected-node="selectedNode">` добавить также **$ctrl**
Тоесть,  в итоге получилось : 
   `<treecontrol class="tree-classic"
                tree-model="$ctrl.dataForTheTree"
                options="$ctrl.treeOptions"
                on-selection="showSelected(node)"
                selected-node="**$ctrl.selectedNode**">
                назва: {{node.name}} ({{node.id}})
    </treecontrol>`

В шаблоне использую как вы указывали $ctrl.selectedNode а в контроллере просто  this.selectedNode.

Comment: странно, но я что то  не могу пометить ваш ответ как ответ.

Comment: Я про это и написал *Попробуйте сделать `$ctrl.selectedNode` в шаблоне*. Также, вангую, что у вас не вызывается функция `showSelected`. Ее также надо указать как `$ctrl.showSelected(node)`

Comment: Потому что у меня не ответ, а комментарий) Можете сами опубликовать ответ, кому-то в будущем может пригодится!